# matplotlib double y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image: the chart]

runoff and value have 13 data, respectively. The double y axis are used for comparing the two sets data every year. But the figure is wrong due to unaligned red symbol and between blue symbol every year. is there any detail I missed？

```
runoff=[1877, 2690.9, 3632, 4525, 1512, 4459, 1614.3, 2595, 1270.2, 2308.2, 2436, 1742.8,2658.7]
TSM=['22.805241997828', '26.649050918463', '23.875097901606', '22.60339679601', '25.898807017902', '28.610553136975', '28.489485098388', '22.206851921378', '21.958918945009', '15.629827074318', '18.894425896003', '20.511980938426', '19.879687929129']

def draw(df):

    font = {'family' : 'Times New Roman',             
        'color'  : 'black'          ,  
        'weight' : 'normal'         ,  
        'size'   : 11 
        }

    fig=plt.figure(11,figsize=(4.5,3))
    ax1=plt.axes([0.10,0.24,0.78,0.73])
    ax2=ax1.twinx()
    matplotlib.rcParams["font.family"] = "Times New Roman"#全局times new roamn
    matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.direction'] = 'in'
    matplotlib.rcParams['ytick.direction'] = 'inout' 
    ax1.plot(value,label='TSM',marker='o',color='red')
    #plt.ylim([10,30])


    ax2.plot(runoff,label='Sediment runoff',marker='s',color='blue',linestyle='--')
    ax2.spines['left'].set_color('red')
    ax2.spines['right'].set_color('blue')
    ax2.tick_params(which='both',color='blue')
    ax1.tick_params(axis='y',which='both',color='red')

    xticks=list(range(0,len(time),2))
    xlabels=[time[index] for index in xticks]
    xticks.append(len(time)+1)
    #xlabels.append('2015')
    #xlabels.append('2016')
    ax1.set_xticks(xticks)
    ax1.set_xticklabels(xlabels,rotation=0,fontdict=font)


    ax2.spines['bottom'].set_linewidth(1.25)
    ax2.spines['left'].set_linewidth(1.25) 
    ax2.spines['right'].set_linewidth(1.25) 
    ax2.spines['top'].set_linewidth(1.25) 

    legend1=ax1.legend(loc=1,ncol=2)
    legend1.get_title().set_fontsize(fontsize=20)
    legend2=ax2.legend(loc=0,bbox_to_anchor=(0.6,0.85),borderaxespad=0.)
    legend2.get_title().set_fontsize(fontsize=20)

    f=plt.gcf()
    f.text(0.001,0.7,u'TSM $(mg/L)$',fontdict=font,color='black',rotation=90)
    f.text(0.5,0.09,u'Time (year)',fontdict=font,color='black')
    f.text(0.99,0.82,u'Sediment runoff ($ton$)',fontdict=font,color='black',rotation=90)  
    f.canvas.draw()
    plt.show()
    return True
```

Comment: Have you tried giving both ``TSM`` and ``runoff`` a common x-array? Like ``plot(t,TSM)`` and ``plot(t,runoff)``.

Answer (score 0):

One straight forward way is to first make sure you address your time in years (2003...2015) correctly from your dataframe to create a list of the years, referred to as 'time' in your code. I have used a simple list(range(..) using Python 3. The 'time' variable as a list of years will make the following line not necessary ("#xticks.append(len(time)+1)"):
Also note that your (df) argument is not necessary since it is not used inside draw().
I have coded an alternative way of combining the legends for the two axes. I have done this in the suggested code by:
1) Creating a combined axes definition (AxesAll = axes1+axes2, not the axes1=...at your previous ax1.plot(...) statement, similar for axes2), and then defining a combined legend for them.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

time = list(range(2003,2016))
#print(time)

runoff=[1877, 2690.9, 3632, 4525, 1512, 4459, 1614.3, 2595, 1270.2, 2308.2, 
2436, 1742.8,2658.7]
TSM=['22.805241997828', '26.649050918463', '23.875097901606', '22.60339679601', '25.898807017902', '28.610553136975', '28.489485098388', '22.206851921378', '21.958918945009', '15.629827074318', '18.894425896003', '20.511980938426', '19.879687929129']

def draw():

    font = {'family' : 'Times New Roman',             
    'color'  : 'black'          ,  
    'weight' : 'normal'         ,  
    'size'   : 11 
    }

    fig=plt.figure(11,figsize=(4.5,3))
    ax1=plt.axes([0.10,0.24,0.78,0.73])
    ax2=ax1.twinx()
    matplotlib.rcParams["font.family"] = "Times New Roman"#全局times new roamn
    matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.direction'] = 'in'
    matplotlib.rcParams['ytick.direction'] = 'inout' 
    axes1 = ax1.plot(TSM,label='TSM',marker='o',color='red')
    #plt.ylim([10,30])


    axes2 = ax2.plot(runoff,label='Sediment　runoff',marker='s',color='blue',linestyle='--')
    ax2.spines['left'].set_color('red')
    ax2.spines['right'].set_color('blue')
    ax2.tick_params(which='both',color='blue')
    ax1.tick_params(axis='y',which='both',color='red')

    xticks=list(range(0,len(time),2))
    xlabels=[time[index] for index in xticks]
    #xticks.append(len(time)+1)
    #xlabels.append('2015')
    #xlabels.append('2016')
    ax1.set_xticks(xticks)
    ax1.set_xticklabels(xlabels,rotation=0,fontdict=font)


    ax2.spines['bottom'].set_linewidth(1.25)
    ax2.spines['left'].set_linewidth(1.25) 
    ax2.spines['right'].set_linewidth(1.25)
    ax2.spines['top'].set_linewidth(1.25) 

    #legend1=ax1.legend(loc=1,ncol=2)
    #legend1.get_title().set_fontsize(fontsize=20)
    #legend2=ax2.legend(loc=0,bbox_to_anchor=(0.6,0.85),borderaxespad=0.)
    #legend2.get_title().set_fontsize(fontsize=20)
    axesAll = axes1+axes2
    labsAll = (l.get_label() for l in axesAll)
    plt.legend(axesAll, labsAll, loc=0)

    f=plt.gcf()
    f.text(0.001,0.7,u'TSM 
    $(mg/L)$',fontdict=font,color='black',rotation=90)
    f.text(0.5,0.09,u'Time (year)',fontdict=font,color='black')
    f.text(0.99,0.82,u'Sediment runoff ($ton$)',fontdict=font,color='black',rotation=90)  
    f.canvas.draw()
    plt.show()
    return True

draw()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a simple problem - you are calling `twinx` on `ax1` to create ax2, before actually setting up the x axis on `ax1`. Move your x axis setup code to just before calling `ax2 = ax1.twinx()`

Move this:

```
xticks=list(range(0,len(time),2))
xlabels=[time[index] for index in xticks]
xticks.append(len(time)+1)
#xlabels.append('2015')
#xlabels.append('2016')
ax1.set_xticks(xticks)
ax1.set_xticklabels(xlabels,rotation=0,fontdict=font)
```

To be here

```
ax1=plt.axes([0.10,0.24,0.78,0.73])
#INSERT HERE
...
#END OF INSERT
ax2=ax1.twinx()
```